# The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly on visual studio for xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I am trying to run application on Xamarin on visual studio, I am getting error as mentioned below and not able to run the application on device or emulator:

```
The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbDebugException: Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.ReadCustomMetadata(BitAccess bits)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction..ctor(ManProcSym proc, BitAccess bits)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFunction.LoadManagedFunctions(BitAccess bits, UInt32 limit, Boolean readStrings)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFuncsFromDbiModule(BitAccess bits, DbiModuleInfo info, IntHashTable names, ArrayList funcList, Boolean readStrings, MsfDirectory dir, Dictionary`2 nameIndex, PdbReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions(Stream read, Dictionary`2& tokenToSourceMapping, String& sourceServerData)
   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.PopulateFunctions()
   at Mono.Cecil.Pdb.PdbReader.ProcessDebugHeader(ImageDebugDirectory directory, Byte[] header)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ProcessDebugHeader()
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadSymbols(ISymbolReader reader)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModuleFrom(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Stream stream, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Compile()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__1.MoveNext()  MyFirstProject
```

Before adding this "Xamarin.Forms.Maps" NuGet package, my application working but as I have added this suddenly application stops running and getting error.

Anybody could help me what causes this type of issue?

Comment: I've started to get this for my Windows Phone project w/in Xamarin.Forms after the newest Visual Studio 2015 RC update. I think for me its to do with the fact that VS2015 is dropping support for windows phone 8.0 and older. I doubt that is your problem here but might help to know that causes a similar error

Comment: Xamarin sure does save a lot of time. -_-

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This issue arise, if your Xamarin.Form version is not compatible/matching with your NuGet package which you have installed.

So, I have just updated Xamarin.Forms for both xx.Droid and PCL and make the match the dependencies with NuGet package.

Now it is working fine. Hope so this will work for you.

Comment: I would also like to add to this that after making sure all `Xamarin.Forms` packages are up to date in all projects, closing and reopening `Visual Studio` usually helps

Comment: Also, try to 'clean solution' if there are missing-files or file-not-found build errors.

Comment: For me, my problem was solved by simply updating all of my NuGet packages to the latest version.

Comment: hi, can you post a screenshot on where to fix this in VS

Answer (score 19):

Delete your old package `/[your project root]/packages/Xamarin.Forms.[old version number]`.

Comment: After trying everything else suggested this is what finally did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This kind of issue may also come if by mistake you have any syntactical error like in my case: two text cells were present in the ListView -

```
<ListView x:Name="ProductsView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding ProductId}" />
            <TextCell Text="{Binding ProductDescription}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I went through other posts for this issue and found the same issue occurred due to the presence of syntactical errors, which VS doesn't report directly. So look for this, otherwise, reinstall the compatible version of `xamarin.forms` -> clean solutions -> rebuild by reopening VS.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Visual Studio/Rider does not handle this error well at all.

Answer (score 4):

I removed all Xamarin references from ALL projects, removed ALL Xamaring packages. Deleted all mention of Xamarin in PROJ files and readded all nuget packages for Xamarin. (lost days on this) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have XML errors in your XAML files, this may happen too. Example:

```
<Label Text="<- go back" />
```

(You cannot use the character `<` there, use `&lt;` instead.)

Or two attributes with the same name:

```
<Label Text="someText" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="someText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Xamarin.Forms to the latest version on both android and iOS project and reopened the project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error with `Xamarin.Mac` in `Visual Studio for Mac`. I `unloded` the `Xamarin.Mac` Project. Than remove it from `solution`. Finally delete the `xamarin.Mac` folder from the solution folder. Atlast `deleted` the `packages` folder from the solution folder. Remove all `nuget packages` from `xamarin forms` project. 
Now I again add the `nuget packages` to xamarin forms project. Added `Xamarin.Mac` project to the solution and make necessary `modifications`. This results in a successful `build`. Though my problem was with `xamarin.mac` this process may solve problem with other `projects` also.

Answer (score 0):

When We Add ContentPage Page in Xamarin.Forms. and in that page we add more then one ContentPage.Content in same page. Then also we get this type of the error.