# Xamarin - The "XamlXTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin, build, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error when trying to build my Xamarin apps in Release. The build in Debug works just fine. This has only started happening lately after updating all nuget packages to the latest version of Xamarin, etc.

Error:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly on visual studio for xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117056/the-xamlctask-task-failed-unexpectedly-on-visual-studio-for-xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

The only fix for me was to downgrade Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Maps from version **2.3.4.247** (currently latest version) to version **2.3.4.231**. I tried uninstalling and installing the latest version before and that did not work unfortunately. Version downgrade fixed the issue for me.